# EInvalidPointer message with 'Invalid Pointer Operation'

Tags: delphi, debugging, exception, delphi-2007

The program compiles and runs successfully (on delphi 2007), but during debugging only, it pops up a message box saying "Invalid Pointer Operation" when shutting the program down. I found none and they execute as expected without any error.

[image: here is screenshot for exception]

When I do tell the compiler to break at Invalid Pointer Operation error, it doesn't do anything but hangs up the program.

How can I resolve this?